# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' while adding two images

Tags: python-3.x

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1=cv2.imread('3.jpg')
img2=cv2.imread('4.jpg')

add = img1 + img2

cv2.imshow('add', add)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Comment: So one of the images is not there and `cv2.imread()` returned `None`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between OpenCV addition and Numpy addition. OpenCV addition is a **saturated operation** while Numpy addition is a **modulo operation**.

Ex::

```
 x = np.uint8([250])
 y = np.uint8([10])
 print cv2.add(x,y) # 250+10 = 260 => 255
 [[255]]
 print x+y          # 250+10 = 260 % 256 = 4
 [4]
```

It will be more visible when you add two images. OpenCV function will provide a better result. So always better stick to OpenCV functions

For NoneType try to output img1 and img2 resp
by using `imshow`

Comment: 1)so, how to add two images in opencv?

Comment: 2) x = np.uint8([250])
 y = np.uint8([10])    is it possible to import image in this way?

Comment: use `cv2.add(img1,img2)` to add the images 
and I am not trying to import the image.
Please read further about numpy :)
I am just showing how numpy array addition is modulo addition as mentioned in my answer.
If you tried to add an image as you have in your question you will not get the desired result.
Hope it helps :))

Comment: For your clarrification range of `uint8` is **0-255** so we get a modulo operation.When you read a image using imread() the return datatype is
`img.dtype` is `np.uint(8)`

Comment: i tried that.i am getting error..cv2.error
  Message=C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::arithm_op